# Creating a list out of my DTO

Tags: java, list, object, dto, getter-setter

I have a year object. For now lets say only two years and its getters and setters

```
private String mYearOne;
private String mYearTwo;
public String getmYearOne() {
    return mYearOne;    }
public void setmYearOne(String mYearOne) {
    this.mYearOne = mYearOne;   }
public String getmYearTwo() {
    return mYearTwo;    }
public void setmYearTwo(String mYearTwo) {
    this.mYearTwo = mYearTwo;   }
```

Then each year has three insurance plans. And its getters and setters.

```
private String healthPlan;
private String carPlan;
private String housePlan;
private String healthPlanTwo;
private String carPlanTwo;
private String housePlanTwo;
public String getHealthPlan() {
    return healthPlan;  }
public void setHealthPlan(String healthPlan) {
    this.healthPlan = healthPlan;   }
public String getCarPlan() {
    return carPlan; }
public void setCarPlan(String carPlan) {
    this.carPlan = carPlan; }
public String getHousePlan() {
    return housePlan;   }
public void setHousePlan(String housePlan) {
    this.housePlan = housePlan; }
public String getHealthPlan() {  //For the second year
    return healthPlan;  }
public void setHealthPlan(String healthPlan) {
    this.healthPlan = healthPlan;   }
public String getCarPlan() {
    return carPlan; }
public void setCarPlan(String carPlan) {
    this.carPlan = carPlan; }
public String getHousePlan() {
    return housePlan;   }
public void setHousePlan(String housePlan) {
    this.housePlan = housePlan; }
public String getHealthPlanTwo() {
    return healthPlanTwo;   }
public void setHealthPlanTwo(String healthPlanTwo) {
    this.healthPlanTwo = healthPlanTwo; }
public String getCarPlanTwo() {
    return carPlanTwo;  }
public void setCarPlanTwo(String carPlanTwo) {
    this.carPlanTwo = carPlanTwo;   }
public String getHousePlanTwo() {
    return housePlanTwo;    }
public void setHousePlanTwo(String housePlanTwo) {
    this.housePlanTwo = housePlanTwo;   }
```

You will notice the code is bulky. I need to define them in a `<list>` of year. So that if 10 years are considered, I would have 10 multiplied
by 3 = 30 plans and its getters and setters respectively.

How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet will be to maintain a count of number of years and arraylists for the insurance plans. This way, you can get the arraylist once and get the insurance plan details for whatever year you actually want. This will be characterized by a single insurance plan arraylist and a single arraylist for years.

```
private ArrayList mYear;
private ArrayList healthPlan;
private ArrayList carPlan;
private ArrayList housePlan;

public String getHousePlanForYear(String year){
return housePlan.get(mYear.indexOf(year));
}

public void setHousePlanForYear(String housePlan, String year){
this.housePlan.set(mYear.indexOf(year), housePlan);
}
```

Similarly for the other plans. Of course, all this is assuming that the year is always present  and other boundary conditions. Just add your boundary checks in these getters and setters and you will be good to go. :)

Comment: In your example how can a void method have a return type?

Comment: hehe.. sorry.. that was a mistake I overlooked.. Thanks for bringing it up!

Answer (score 1):

I see a design/domain modelling problem here. A person can ideally have multiple "plans" and "riders" attached to each plan. This should clearly be abstracted away properly by creating a "PlanCollection" class or simply maintaining a list of "plans" which all extend/implement a common "Plan" class/interface.

Each plan can have a "plan" duration and a start date. Also, logically, you don't attach plans to "year" but the timeline information is encapsulated in the Plan itself (like start and duration as mentioned above).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at enums and maps. The enum would specify car, house etc.

You could create a map that takes an enum as key and a List of years as the key. Don't be tempted to create YearThree etc.

On a note of style: if you intend to use m to prefix fields, take the m **out** of the setter. E.g. setYearOne not setmYearOne.

Choose your types wisely, don't use a String if an int is better.